# How do I add custom attributes to a form_for?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Ok, so here is my code.

```
<%= form_for @quiz do |f|%>
  <% @questions.shuffle.each do |q| %>
    # get_answers returns an array of 4 random answers
    <% answers = q.get_answers %>
    <%= f.label q.inquest %><br>
    <% answers.each do |a| %>
      <%= f.radio_button <need help here!>, a %>
      <%= f.label <need help here!>, a %><br>
      <%= f.hidden_field <need help here!>, q.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

my quiz table has the attributes

```
concept_id
user_id
```

how do I add custom attributes that I can have access to in the post action? It should be dynamic so it can scale with how many questions there are. I want something like this for my params.

```
{
  user_answers: {
    question1: {
      :question_id
      :answer
    {
  }
}
```

Depending on how many questions there are, it'll go like question1, 2, 3, 4 etc..

The hidden_field would carry with question_id while the radio_button would carry the answer. I don't need it to save or anything, I just need access to them

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Cool - looks good.. so I'd start by using `each_with_index` (so you know which answer you're up to) and using the index as part of the name of the form-field. eg `<%= f.hidden_field "question_id_#{idx}", :value => q.id %>`

Comment: Thanks! I just added that, I also added `<%=f.radio_button "answer#{index+1}", a%>` for the radio button, but I get a undefined method error. It's because `"answer#{index+1}"` not a attribute for @quiz. How would I get that to work?

Comment: As you you found, you use the `_tag` versions instead of just the `form_for` versions :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I realized that I shouldn't have called those form tags on f. instead have them as their own form tags

for example:

`radio_button_tag` instead of `f.radio_button`

Comment: Can you please add a code sample?